# Fail to install mysql on cygwin, No curses/termcap library found

Tags: mysql, cygwin

Fail to install mysql on cygwin.

When do ./configure, experienced following error:

checking for termcap functions library... configure: error: No curses/termcap library found

any idea?

Comment: Yap, the curses/termcap library is missing. SCNR ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.

Run cygwin setup (http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe) and then in the dialog search for libncurses. Choose the appropriate one and install it. Also search for libtermcap and install it.

That should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't have the libncurses package installed in your Cygwin setup.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also got the same missing library error, but the cause was different. I did install cygwin and the libraries, but on the same laptop I already had Perl for Windows installed. Via the PATH the gcc compiler was found in

```
c:\perl\... instead  of in c:\cygwin\...
```

This mashed things up. Quick and dirty solution was to rename `c:\perl` keeping PATH the same.